# Build 32bits ruby using rvm in RHEL 6(x86_64 arch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, redhat, rhel

Hope someone can shed a light on this issue for me. I am building ruby 32bit in RHEL 6 x86_64 using rvm. Followed this [guide](http://www.jeffmdean.com/2012/3/13/developing-locally-with-oracle-and-ruby-on-a-mac)(ignored Mac related stuffs), I ran

> rvm_archflags="-arch i386" CFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386"
>   rvm install 1.9.2

I get an error like this:

```
Error running './configure --disable-install-doc --prefix=/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371 --enable-shared'
```

Trying original method: `rvm install 1.8.7 --32` and got this:

> 'env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET= CFLAGS=-O3 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe
>   -no-cpp-precomp CCFLAGS=-arch i386 -g -Os -pipe CXXFLAGS=-arch i386 -g -Os -pipe LDFLAGS=-arch i386 -bind_at_load LDSHARED=cc  -arch i386 -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace ./configure --disable-install-doc --prefix=/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371 --enable-shared'

Looking at the config.log, it says C compiler cannot create executables. From the look of the errors, I guess it mismatched the target machine(Mac instead of RHEL). I don't quite understand why because the gcc is definitely built for x86_64 Red Hat linux. Can someone give me a hint on this issue?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling in 32bit requires using the `-m32` option on linux. The `-arch i386` option is Mac specific.

You will, of course require the full suite of 32bit development libraries.

Comment: yes, you are correct about the flag. It does look like I don't have 32bit libraries. Do you know how can I install them though yum?I did a search and the results are all for x86_64 or i686. It's my first time working with RHEL.

Comment: i686 carries the same meaning as i386 in this context, so you should install the i686 versions. The real question is why are you not building 64bit? Deploying to a 32bit system? Unless you have a dependency on something that is only available in 32bit you should build in 64bit

Comment: Thanks @Petesh, figured out that RHEL 6 doesn't have any 32bit libraries in its standard(thats why yum repo doesnt display any i386 libs). They are basically not official supported. Im just gonna backport the OS to version 5. Much safer route. The answer to your question is because Im working with a Oracle DB and the Oracle ruby gem is 32bit compatible only hence need 32bit ruby.

Comment: The answer over in superuser instructs on how to make the 32bit packages available - http://serverfault.com/questions/289400/rhel-6-x64-running-32-bit-applications Of course it would be a binary-only package causing trouble